# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: php, api, request, discord, put

By wishing to make a POST request with the Discord APIs to allow a user to join my server directly after having authenticated with the OAuth an authorization error this product while I have specified the access token in the fields. It sends me " failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED".

Here is my code

```php
$join = 'https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/538087318284795905/members/' . $userapi->id .'';
    $data = ['access_token' => session('access_token')];
    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'PUT',
            "header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . session('access_token'),
            'content' => json_encode($data)
        ]
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($join, false, $context);
```

[image: Discord Developer Portal Documentation]

Comment: Should this ` $data = ['access_token' => session('access_token')]` be ` $data = ['access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token']]`? I have never seen that function in PHP before. Otherwise, are you using a library which provides that? If so, which one?

A sure way to know whether it is giving you the string you expect is to var_dump it, then you know whether it's got whitespace or weird encoding. You could also try making the request manually with an API interrogating REST client such as Insomnia.

Comment: @MichaelThompson Access_token is the variable that we obtain per session once the user authenticated to his Discord account, token that I managed to visualize with a var_dump however according to the discord documentation that is required in the requests and this that I did that sends me a 401 error while theoretically that should not be the case

Comment: I have looked into the documentation a little and I find that the Authorization header can be set to bot. I imagine that it would make sense you want to authenticate the bot to the channel in the header, because it is what should have the permission to modify the guild, rather than the user who currently has no permission to the guild. At this point, I would try changing the Authorization header to bot, and making sure the bot has the CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE.

Comment: @MichaelThompson it does not work either with a bot token and in any case you must have access to the user's access_token